# Working with AJAX and Javascript responses in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm having a bit of trouble working with AJAX and Ruby on Rails with JQuery. I'm trying to use the AJAX method in JQuery, do a GET request with it, and transfer the response into Ruby so I can use it in my controllers and views. Here's the script that I want to run at the bottom of my view:

```
function onClick() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/posts.json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(response) {
      return response;
    }
  });
};

onClick();
```

Is there a way I can transfer this response into ruby, so I can use it in my controllers like this? I want 'response' to be what is returned from the AJAX request:

```
def index
  @response = response
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up the **front-end** and the **back-end** of your application. Your JavaScript code lives in the front-end, which is actually running in your visitors' browsers; whereas your Rails controller lives in the back-end, which is running far, far away on your web server. It's possible to send data back and forth between them, but only as part of the **request lifecycle**, which I'll summarize as:

1. Visitor makes a **request** to load your webpage.
2. Your server & Rails receive the request, and decide how to **route** it to a **controller**
3. Your controller handles the request, does stuff, and then **renders** a **view** into HTML (or JSON, or whatever format you want to send back).
4. This HTML (or JSON) is sent back to the visitor as the **response**. This response contains all of your JavaScript code, as well (actually, your JS code is usually sent in a separate request, made in parallel by the visitor's browser... but it all ends up in your visitor's browser nonetheless).

So, what you're asking for -- to have a JavaScript call send its data to the controller -- is impossible to do in one request. You could have the JavaScript send that data through a **new** request to the controller, but the visitor wouldn't see that.

Instead, I think you just want to have your controller make this web request, or -- since the request is on your same server anyway -- have your controller simply load all the Posts in your database and send that data to the view. For example:

```
# app/controllers/things_controller.rb
class ThingsController
  def index
    @posts_json = Posts.all.to_json
  end
end
```

Then, pass that variable into your JavaScript via a small script in your view (this part is a bit tricky; you need to tell Rails that it's okay to print the JSON string as-is, without sanitizing it):

```
# app/views/things/index.html.erb
<h1> Posts! </h1>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var posts = <%=raw @posts_json %>;
  alert("I've got " + posts.length + " posts loaded.");
</script>
```

The above is a fairly standard strategy. Hope this explanation has helped!

Comment: Thanks, that explanation really helped. So I should make the controller access the Javascript from an API (if I use one), and then serve it up raw in the view.